# Could DocuSign Connect connect to our server with our PKI certificate?

Tags: ssl, docusignapi

To connect to our applications, user must authentificate with a private certificate PKI delivered by our company.

For the security staff, Docusign Connect is an user like an other and must be respect this security rules.

So,  is it possible to set DocuSign Connect with our certificate PKI ?
And how can we set in Docusign Connect ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this answer from DocuSign : it is not possible to set DocuSign Connect with a certificate PKI.